# How to construct a parabola given its focus and two points on it

Tags: conic-sections

I need to construct the guideline/directrix and the axis of symmetry of a parabola.

I’ve been given A its focus and two points B and C going through the parabola.

Could you please point me to the technique on how to do this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: perpendicular bisector potentially.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Draw two circles, having $B$ and $C$ as centers, and passing through $A$. The directrix of the required parabola is any common tangent to both circles.

[image]

Comment: What about the axis of symmetry?

Comment: @Narasimham Just drop the perpendicular from focus to directrix.

Comment: I would draw them both in either case of solution construction,

Comment: Included the parabola axes in your construction. It  is not any new construction,  just that I felt the axis should be also added as OP wanted.The method follows the way eccentricity =1 is defined as locus for parabola between focus/directrix.

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful

Answer (score 1):

Repeat of Aretino's construction, including axes of symmetry.Points $(p,q)$ are vertices of the two parabolas possible with two direct tangent directrices  shown.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, also for correcting the question!